# How can other users obtain tokens for my in-development slack app?

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

**TLDR**: I have a slack app for managing private channels in its development workspace and tokens for it that inherit my user privileges. How can someone else in the same workspace obtain tokens for this app that inherit their user privileges instead?

Ok, so the background of this is: i need to manage the membership of a bunch of private channels based on some more or less complicated ldap-related conditions. For this, i wanted to write a simple Python program that got the membership of the channels in question, did its ldap magic to figure out who should be where, and then make it so.

I have implemented this and all works fine so far. The issue now is that i (that is my slack user) cannot be in all of these channels for privacy reasons. The API and Bot tokens i have obtained inherit all of my own user privileges. That means i can neither see nor administrate the channels that i'm not a part of.

Based on what i've read in the documentation of the Slack API, there's a way to have another user go through the OAuth process for the app that i created to get the tokens, get their own tokens, and use them with the Python program that i wrote. That would be fine, but i can't figure out how to do this.

Noone else has access to the app directly. The documentation makes it seem like i need to give people a specially formatted link (the "Add to Slack Button") that they can click on to get taken through the process. But that seems to require a "redirect URL". I'm not sure what this is and the documentation isn't very clear on it, but it seems they are assuming that the app is running on a server somewhere and will need to answer requests from Slack or something. That's not the case. It's a fairly simple Python script, not some always-up cloud app that will be responding to Slack Events.

So it feels like i'm missing something. Either i have some fundamental misconception about how this is supposed to work, or there is a simple way for someone else to get a token like that and i'm not seeing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If you want other users to authenticate your app (e.g. generate tokens so your app can perform tasks on the users behalf) you need to create an [installation routine using Ouath 2.0](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth). That installation routine is a small web app that has the "Add to Slack" button, a HTML interface and is able to run through the Oauth 2.0 process. That web app needs to run on a public web server.

For development purpose that web server can also run on your local dev machine with a VPN tunnel to the public Internet. Slack recommends using the VPN service [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) for that purpose.

Comment: Darn. I was really hoping not having to do that, since it seems like setting up this web app will be more work than writing the actual program i'm trying to create. But thank you for the answer.

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer solved your question, please consider marking it as solution (clicking the green checkmark). Ty

Comment: @DominikSteenken If you are looking for an easy solution to run your installation routine check out serverless platforms. One nice solution I tried out today is NOW. It also has an interesting free tier and I can confirm it work with Slack: https://zeit.co/home